# Do other (none-primary) attributes affect my character?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Star Wars: The Old Republic, there exist datacrons which provide a permanent stat boost to your character. Different datacrons enhance different attributes.

My main is a Sith Inquisitor. I can see an obvious benefit in picking up `Endurance` and `Willpower` datacrons (as these are the primary stats for my class). I assume (please correct me if I'm wrong) that there is some benefit to picking `Strength` for the rare occasion when I use my lightsaber.

But is there any benefit to collecting the `Cunning` or `Aim` datacrons other than the small amount of experience and codex entry?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because all main stats have been replaced with Mastery, which affects all classes the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** For the Inquisitor specifically there is no benefit from Cunning or Aim. When you mouseover these attributes on your character window you'll notice that cunning and aim provide bonuses to your ranged and tech abilities. However, Inquisitors do not have any ranged or tech abilities (you can see what skills fall into what category in your abilities window on the right hand side, in your case, Force/Active will be the two primary ones).

Answer (score 3):

Every 10 points in a stat that isn't your classes primary stat provides 1 point of bonus damage to the ability type associated with that stat. Every 140 points provides 1% crit. Your primary stat provides a bonus at the same rate to *all* ability types.

For **Strength** this is force based melee abilities, for **Aim** this is blaster attacks and non-force ranged attacks, and for **Cunning**, this is non-force tech abilities.

In other words, as an Assassin, you'll get some, but very little benefit from Strength, and as an Inquisitor, nearly none. And Cunning and Aim will provide no benefit to either AC.

Similarly, Sith Warriors/Jedi Knights will derive similar minimal benefits from Willpower, while Bounty Hunters/Troopers will see a small gain from Cunning, and Agents/Smugglers from Aim.

Answer (score 1):

not cunning and aim, but there is another attribute that some datacrons have that do benefit you... Presence (makes your companions better)

Answer (score 0):

Every datacron you receive gives you experience if you are under level 55.  So don't pass one up if its easily accessible.